# Can't log into minicube! message launching miniKube has me concerned: "Unable to resolve the Docker CLI context" "The system cannot find the path"

Tags: docker, minikube

This command was run on a Windows 11 machine through Visual Studio Code Terminal window and the minikube sart command was on the command line of that Terminal Window.  The "unable to.." command has be concerned.  Since Docker is widely used I imagine people here can offer insight.

```
PS C:\Users\wmmth\source\docker-nodejs-basic-demo-master> `minikube start --driver=docker`

**W0930 18:48:02.301808   16048 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\wmmth\.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.**

  minikube v1.31.2 on Microsoft Windows 11 Home 10.0.22621.2283 Build 22621.2283

✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile

  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube

  Pulling base image ...

  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...

  Preparing Kubernetes v1.27.4 on Docker 24.0.4 ...

  Verifying Kubernetes components...

    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5

  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass

      Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

by the way,

```
minikube status
```

has similar results:

```
minikube status 

          


 W0930 19:11:44.872755    5636 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the 
current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\wmmth\.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the 
path specified.
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get the following error, your installation of Minikube and Docker Desktop likely has some problems.

```
Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open 
C:\\Users\\wmmth.docker\\contexts\\meta\\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified
```

The below content taken from this [doc](https://devopsbuild.com/minikube-unable-to-resolve-the-current-docker-cli-context-default/) by Serdal kepil Follow below steps to resolve the above error

> There are four ways we can fix your problem. I hope one of them can
> offer assistance with your issue.
> **Option 1**: You can use this command to update the default context for Docker.
>
> ```
> docker context use default
> ```
>
> **Option 2**: Please try this command if the last one didn't work.
>
> ```
> kubectl config set-context minikube
> ```
>
> **Option 3**: You have docker installation  and it has been set to be deployed to Kubernetes. Minikube is not a part of this integration.
>
> You can disable this previously enabled Kubernetes from Docker Desktop
> settings/preferences, uncheck Enable Kubernetes
>
> **Option 4**: You can remove docker local meta file. This is the last
> option
>
> **Please follow these steps below**:
>
> **1**.Stop Docker Desktop and all containers.
>
> **2**.Find the path under your local user:
>
> ```
> ~/.docker/contexts/meta/(some sha256)/meta.json
> ```
>
> Using Windows it should be on:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.docker\contexts\meta\(some sha256)\meta.json
> ```
>
> **3**. Then directly delete the hashed folder which is some sha256 and    includes a meta.json file.

> **4**. Restart Docker and check again.

Comment: like magic the first command worked